# Something wrong with xml serialization/deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7

I'm dipping my feet into Windows Phone development and are starting to get to terms with some of the features of Silverlight on WP, but I'm struggling with XML:

I'm trying to serialize some objects into an XML and then read the said XML and serialize it into objects again. Then I'll use that to populate a listbox by putting an `ObservableCollection` as the `ItemsSource` of the listbox.

I've already made sure that the databinding works properly; if I just generate the objects and put them into an `Observable Collection` and then put that as the `ItemsSource`, there are no problems. It would seem that it's the XML part of my code that's faulting. Everything compiles and executes nice enough, but the listbox remains empty :(

This code executes as the app launches (not very effective but works for my testing):

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<Quote> quotes = new ObservableCollection<Quote>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Quote quote = new Quote()
            {
                Author = "Author #" + i.ToString(),
                QuoteText = "This is quote #" + i.ToString(),
            };

            quotes.Add(quote);
        }

        XmlWriterSettings xmlwrtrstngs = new XmlWriterSettings();
        xmlwrtrstngs.Indent = true;
        using(IsolatedStorageFile isostrg = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using(IsolatedStorageFileStream isoflstrm = isostrg.OpenFile("Quotes.xml", FileMode.Create))
            {
                XmlSerializer xmlsrlzr = new XmlSerializer(typeof(QuoteCollection));
                using(XmlWriter xmlwrtr = XmlWriter.Create(isoflstrm, xmlwrtrstngs))
                {
                    xmlsrlzr.Serialize(xmlwrtr, quoteCollection);
                }
            }
        }

        loadData();
    }

    void loadData()
    {
        try
        {
            using(IsolatedStorageFile isostrg = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            {
                using(IsolatedStorageFileStream isoflstrm = isostrg.OpenFile("Quotes.xml", FileMode.Open))
                {
                    XmlSerializer xmlsrlzr = new XmlSerializer(typeof(QuoteCollection));
                    QuoteCollection quoteCollectionFromXML = (QuoteCollection)xmlsrlzr.Deserialize(isoflstrm);
                    LstBx.ItemsSource = quoteCollectionFromXML.Quotes;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {

            Console.Write("Something went wrong with the XML!");
        }


    }
```

**QuoteCollection**

```
public class QuoteCollection : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ObservableCollection<Quote> quotes;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ObservableCollection<Quote> Quotes
    {
        get { return quotes; }

        set
        {
            if(quotes != value)
            {
                quotes = value;
                raisePropertyChanged("Quotes");
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void raisePropertyChanged(string argPropertyChanged)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(argPropertyChanged));
        }
    }
}
```

**Quote**

```
public class Quote : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string author;
    string quoteText;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Author
    {
        get
        {
            return author;
        }

        set
        {
            if(author != value)
            {
                author = value;
                onPropertyChanged("Author");
            }
        }
    }

    public string QuoteText
    {
        get
        {
            return quoteText;
        }

        set
        {
            if(quoteText != value)
            {
                quoteText = value;
                onPropertyChanged("QuoteText");
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void onPropertyChanged(string argProperty)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(argProperty));
        }
    }
}
```

Any insight would be most appreciated :)

Comment: Where is `QuoteCollection` defined? You are serializing using it as the type, but actually writing out an `ObservableCollection<Quote>`.

Comment: Provide more details about QuoteCollection class

Comment: Yeah, if this code compiles, it means you are serializing something entirely different than what you are populating with `Quotes`.

Comment: @tallseth Jesus, you're right. Can't believe I didn't see this until now. Forgot to put the `ObservableCollection` into the `QuoteCollection` instance I'd made previously (not shown in the code posted). Thanks a bunch dude :)

Comment: Well if @HiTechMagic puts an answer down, you should give him credit for it, I didn't notice until I saw his comment. :)

Comment: I would love for @HiTechMagic to put an answer down. I wish for him to get the credit, but I put in the answer myself as a precaution, to be able to mark the question as answered if he didn't

Comment: @tallseth, Jon Stødle. Just takes time to get back to previous questions. Thanks for the credit. Added as answer below. ALso +1 for providing decent code and question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are serializing using `QuoteCollection` as the type, but actually writing out an `ObservableCollection<Quote>`.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to put the ObservableCollection into the QuoteCollection instance I'd made previously (not shown in the code posted).